# route error render partial another controller without a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can render partial and all that, but the problem is when I want to submit a form to another controller I get a route error.

So I have this main page, spree to be precise. A form is created with its controller. I want this form to be within the main page of spree. But when I get to my page, and click the button, it gives me route error. When I do render partial and change the file just to a view, I can see my forms. I don't have a model. I just want to simply submit to the controller.

on the main spree page

```
<%= render partial: '/contact/maillist' %>
```

also tried

```
<%= render template: '/contact/maillist' %>
```

View, also tried `controller: /contact`

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "contact", action: "maillist"}, method: "post") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add Me", remote:true %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class ContactController <Spree::BaseController 
def maillist
    #...whatever, don't think this is the issue?
end
end
```

routes.rb

```
#things i tried...all doesn't work

 get 'contact/maillist' => 'contact#maillist'
 post 'contact/maillist' => 'contact#maillist'
 match 'contact', to: 'contact#maillist', via: :post
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your form_tag to one of the below

```
<%= form_tag('contact/maillist', method: "post") do %>
```

or

```
<%= form_tag(url_for(controller: 'contact', action: 'maillist'), method: "post") do %>
```